# How do i get the `dirname` of last argument of previous command?

Tags: bash

I frequently find myself in the following situation:

```
mv picture /very/long/path/favicon.ico
cd !$
```

The second command fails (as expected) because `!$` is `Not a directory`. Is there some bash history substitution magic that takes me to `/very/long/path`?

Comment: Well, `cd /very/long/path && mv $OLDPWD/picture .` does save me from writing out that long path twice. But this issue might be too trivial to make me changing my habits. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!$:h` does exactly what was required:

```
mv picture /very/long/path/favicon.ico
cd !$:h
```

Source: `man bash`, look for the string `trailing filename`.

Comment: great tip. This could also be profitably aliased

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage `$_` instead, which expands to the last argument of the last executed command. Then a simple parameter expansion to strip off the portion after the last `/` would do:

```
${_%/*}
```

So:

```
cd "${_%/*}"
```

Comment: Thanks. Wait a second i'll `man bash` and find how this works. :)

Comment: @pii_ke: Add this function to your `~/.bashrc` and use `x`: `x() { cd "${_%/*}"; }`

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do that using the dirname command

```
cd $(dirname !$);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this approach to get the last command, question is what you wanna do with it.
[Get bash history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script)